# Google API for home automation with Raspberry pi/arduino/esp32

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, esp8266, google-assistant-sdk, home-automation

Hello I'm currently interested in finding a way to use Google assistant on my cellphone in order to activate GPIO pins on a raspberry pi/Arduino/esp32. I would like to discard options with web interfaces like ifttt or others but I'd prefer to use a library or something else on my arduino/raspberry/esp32 program (preferably in C or python). Maybe a thing that through Google assistant and internet sends a code to my raspi/arduino/esp32 and gets executed by a program running on it. Any suggestions/solutions?

Comment: I've voted to close this question, as asking for suggestions like this is off-topic here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the [smart home documentation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/overview) and follow the [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/smarthome-washer/#0) to learn more about the platform.